# Auto Search Textbox with comma separator in visualforce (mutliselect autocomplete)

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, search, inputtext

I want to create a `auto search textbox in visualforce`. There are many blogs about this scenario is available. But how to make that `textbox to search multiple values like after selecting a value from suggestions user can enter comma and then search for another value likewise`.

for example : youtube tags adding textbox.

I found  [this](http://www.forcesecret.com/thoughts/beautiful-ajax-enabled-select-list-with-pagination-2/) blog for my above requirement, but when I type anything in a textbox it is not showing any suggestions.

Comment: seems like you are looking for mutliselect autocomplete..  check this demo https://ap2-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/pages/MultiSelectAutoComplete  sorce code https://github.com/RatanPaul/VisualforceMultiSelectAutoComplete

Comment: In case you need help with what you have so far..please post your code and let us know if there were any errors so its easier to help you.

Comment: @Ratan and Richard - Thanks for your valuable comments. I checked the demo of that textbox which Ratan posted. That is exactly what I was looking for. I'll work on that. Thanks

Comment: @Ratan - Superb work. It is working perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ratan: Can you please add your comment as an answer so that OP can accept it which will help other fellow members having same question.

Comment: @Ratan - I selected as best answer. But I have other problem how do I renrender that component in my vfp. In my vfp am doing add/delete row functionality. So within that repeat component am adding this component. But am not able to get it correctly. If you wish, i could add snippet and screenshot to this question.

Comment: @sfdc i suggest ask a new question with your issue to get more attention..

Comment: @Ratan - [check this thread](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111808/problem-with-renrendering-a-component-in-vfp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need multiselect autocomplete functionality.

> [**Check this Demo**](https://ap2-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/pages/MultiSelectAutoComplete)
>
> [**Installation package**](https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t900000002Zmq)

Github repository for [**mutiselect autocomplete.**](https://github.com/RatanPaul/VisualforceMultiSelectAutoComplete)

Try this if you face any issue then let us know in community.