# Problem with reRendering a component in vfp

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, rerender, action

I am doing a Add/Delete row functionality in vfp. Within this add/delete row pageblock am calling a component(which is having textbox). When I click on add row button it is rerendering the component but it rerendering two textboxes instead of one textbox.

[image]

Below is visualforce component for that particular textbox(Assign user textbox)

```
<apex:component controller="RN_MultiselectAutoCompleteCtrl">
    <apex:attribute name="style" type="String" description="TODO: Describe me"/>
    <apex:attribute name="AvailableOptions" description="Options list for left listbox." type="SelectOption[]" required="true"  assignTo="{!leftOptions}"/>
    <apex:attribute name="SelectedOptions" description="Options list for right listbox." type="SelectOption[]" required="true"  assignTo="{!rightOptions}"/>

    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.multiSelectAutoComplete, 'js/jquery.min.js')}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.multiSelectAutoComplete, 'js/jquery.tokeninput.js')}" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.multiSelectAutoComplete, 'css/token-input-facebook.css')}" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.multiSelectAutoComplete, 'css/token-input-listStyle.css')}" />
     <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#myAutocomplete").tokenInput({!MultiselectOptions},{preventDuplicates: true});
            });
    </script>
    <apex:inputHidden value="{!strSelectedOptions}" id="hiddenInputId" />
    <input type="text" id="myAutocomplete" style="width:100px;" onchange="$('[id$=hiddenInputId]').val($('#myAutocomplete').val());AF();"/>
    <apex:actionFunction name="AF" action="{!assignToSelectedOption}" rerender="DummyIdreRender"/>

</apex:component>
```

Am calling this component in VFP

```
<apex:page standardController="Module__c" extensions="ModuleCtrlCls" id="thePage" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock id="pb" >
            <apex:pageblockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>

            </apex:pageblockButtons>
            <apex:pagemessages />
            <apex:actionregion >
            <apex:pageblockSection title="Project" >              
                <apex:inputField value="{!Module__c.Project__c}"/>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
            </apex:actionregion>

             <apex:actionregion > 
            <apex:pageblock id="pb1">
                <apex:pageblockButtons >
                    <apex:commandbutton value="Add Module" action="{!Add}" rerender="pb1"/> 
                </apex:pageblockButtons>

                     <apex:repeat value="{!lstInner}" var="e1" id="therepeat">

                         <apex:panelgrid columns="3">

                             <apex:panelGrid title="Module Component" >
                                <apex:facet name="header"><label style="font-weight:bold;font-size:91%;color:#4a4a56;padding-left:127px;">Module Component</label></apex:facet><br/>
                                <apex:inputfield value="{!e1.mod.Module_Component__c}" style="height:80px;width:240px;margin-left:55px;"/>
                             </apex:panelGrid>

                             <apex:panelGrid title="Assign Users" >
                                <apex:facet name="header"><label style="font-weight:bold;font-size:91%;color:#4a4a56;padding-left:130px;">Assign User</label></apex:facet><br/>

                                 <!----COMPONENT---->
                                <c:RN_MultiselectAutoComplete AvailableOptions="{!lstAvailableOptions}" SelectedOptions="{!lstSelectedOptions}" />


                             </apex:panelGrid>

                             <apex:panelGrid title="Delete Module">
                                <apex:facet name="header"><label style="font-weight:bold;font-size:91%;color:#4a4a56;"></label></apex:facet><br/>                  
                                <apex:commandButton value="Delete Module" action="{!Del}" rerender="pb1" style="margin-top:75px;">
                                    <apex:param name="rowToBeDeleted" value="{!e1.recCount}" assignTo="{!selectedRowIndex}"></apex:param>
                                </apex:commandButton>
                             </apex:panelGrid>
                         </apex:panelgrid>
                    </apex:repeat>

                </apex:pageblock>  
                </apex:actionregion>             
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

visualforce page controller

```
public class ModuleCtrlCls {

    //will hold the account records to be saved
    public List<Module__c> lstAcct  = new List<Module__c>();

    //list of the inner class
    public List<innerClass> lstInner 
    {   get;set;    }

    //will indicate the row to be deleted
    public String selectedRowIndex
    {get;set;}  

    //no. of rows added/records in the inner class list
    public Integer count = 1;
    //{get;set;}

    //getter setter for searching textbox
    public List<SelectOption> lstAvailableOptions {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> lstSelectedOptions {get;set;}



    //add one more row
    public void Add()
    {   
        count = count+1;
        addMore();      
    }

    /*Begin addMore*/
    public void addMore()
    {
        //call to the iner class constructor
        innerClass objInnerClass = new innerClass(count);

        //add the record to the inner class list
        lstInner.add(objInnerClass);    
        system.debug('lstInner---->'+lstInner);            
    }/* end addMore*/

    /* begin delete */
    public void Del()
    {
        system.debug('selected row index---->'+selectedRowIndex);
        lstInner.remove(Integer.valueOf(selectedRowIndex)-1);
        count = count - 1;

    }/*End del*/



    /*Constructor*/
    public ModuleCtrlCls(ApexPages.StandardController ctlr)
    {

        lstInner = new List<innerClass>();
        addMore();
        selectedRowIndex = '0';

        //search textbox 
        lstAvailableOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        lstSelectedOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        for(User objAccount:[SELECT Id, Name FROM User])
        {
            lstAvailableOptions.add(new SelectOption(objAccount.Id, objAccount.Name));
        }


    }/*End Constructor*/


    /*Inner Class*/
    public class innerClass
    {       
        /*recCount acts as a index for a row. This will be helpful to identify the row to be deleted */
        public String recCount
        {get;set;}


        public Module__c mod
        {get;set;}

        /*Inner Class Constructor*/
        public innerClass(Integer intCount)
        {
            recCount = String.valueOf(intCount);        

            /*create a new account*/
            mod = new Module__c();

        }/*End Inner class Constructor*/    
    }/*End inner Class*/
}/*End Class*/
```

Comment: hey sfdc looks like your re rendering causing this issue.

Comment: Could you add your controller too?

Comment: @ShaileshDeshpande - Updated with controller cls

Comment: @Ratan - Yeah there is some problem with rerendering only. If I add simple textbox instead of component then it is working perfectly, but with component it is not working properly.

Comment: Could you try putting your command button (Add) in a separate pageblock and rerender pb1?

Comment: It looks to me as though your jQuery `<apex:actionFunction name="AF" action="{!assignToSelectedOption}" rerender="DummyIdreRender"/>` rerender actions "could" be in conflict with your controller's action methods being called from your page's command buttons like: `<apex:commandButton value="Delete Module" action="{!Del}" rerender="pb1" style="margin-top:75px;"> <apex:param name="rowToBeDeleted" value="{!e1.recCount}" assignTo="{!selectedRowIndex}"></apex:param>`

Comment: @ShaileshDeshpande - I tried replacing Add row button in separate pageblock too. But problem continues.

Comment: @crmprogdev - I tried removing that actionFunction in component. But problem continues.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my comments. I think it's more that your jQuery may not be needed. You have getters and setters via your inner method that collect a list of the records to added and deleted. Just call the actionmethods from commandbuttons. Doesn't appear to me that the jQuery serves any purpose. No ActionFunction is required for that.